# How to divide fixed height container into 80% and 20%

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a `fixed position` container which i wanted to divide into 2 halves i,e

`80%` and `20%` **bottom**

**such that i should look like this:**

[image]

**Note**: it should adjust itself on window resize

**[here](https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/yxZqzW) is codepen:**

**here is what i have tried:**

```css
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 100%;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border: 3px solid red;
    color:white;
}
.stories-preview-wrapper{
  height: 20%;
  border:3px solid green;
  width:210px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper" class="toggled hidden-xs">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="stories-preview-wrapper">
             <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
              </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any other stuff in div id wrapper? why not applying fixed position on it?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look:

```css
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 100%;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 210px;
    height: calc(80vh - 6px); /* As you give a border of 3px */
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border: 3px solid red;
    color:white;
}
.stories-preview-wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  height: calc(20vh - 6px); /* As you give a border of 3px */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  width: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled hidden-xs">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="stories-preview-wrapper">
             <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
              </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: please a bit explanation

Comment: I used vh unit instead of %. vh is viewport height. It adjusts with the window height.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in an other solution. Have a look at [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Check this out for further details:

```css
.row{
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 500px;
  grid-template-rows: 80% 20%;
}


#first {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

#second {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="item" id="first">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="item" id="second">
             <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
              </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```